# Angular CLI: generate SASS project from existing project

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I've began working on an Angular CLI generated project and realized I forgot the `--style=sass`flag. 
Is there any way to *convert* my project to enable SASS with the Angular CLI?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can set the default style on an existing project

```
ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

and in angular-cli.json file change **style.css** to **style.scss**

```
"apps":[{
  "styles":[
     "styles.scss"
   ]
}]
```

Comment: The specified command ("set") is invalid. For a list of available options,
run "ng help".

Did you mean "new"?

Answer (score 12):

In Angular 6+ if you are getting console warning after doing `ng config defaults.styleExt = scss`

such as below is because of [single dashes are not supported anymore](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10243#issuecomment-379747092)

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
 Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(defaults).
```

You can run below command to change schematics

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss
```

You need to do two manual changes

- Rename `.css` file to `.scss` in the root folder
- Update *angular.json* file with `"styles": ["src/styles.scss"],`

Comment: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "/schematics/@schematics~1angular:component" must NOT have additional properties(styleExt).

Comment: with Angular 9 or later use "ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.style scss"

Answer (score 8):

In angular cli 6  this is depracated

```
ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

You should use this

```
ng config defaults.styleExt = scss
```

Comment: I did and I got this: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(defaults).

Answer (score 2):

just rename existing css files (if any) to sass and add this to angular-cli.json:

```
"defaults": {
    .....
    "styleExt": "sass"
}
```

also look at app/styles section in this file - you should rename filenames here too

Comment: probably also rename the styles inside the `apps.styles` of the `angular-cli.json`